# why Thread run only once

Tags: android, multithreading

So I have a very simple and may be silly question, sorry about that but I really don't know why this Thread is running only once?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Log.e("comes here", "opr");
            if (done) {
                call(tv);
                done = false;
                Log.e("comes here","andr");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                Thread.currentThread().stop();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch
            // block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}).start();
```

I debug it terminates here

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
Log.e("comes here", "opr");
```

and it supposed to run again again and again untill `done =true`

**Update**

now the thread is not terminating

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Log.e("comes here","opr");
                if (done) {
                    call(tvv);
                    done = false;
                    Log.e("comes here","andr");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    //Thread.currentThread().stop();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated
                // catch
                // block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (!done);
    }
}).start();
```

I can't set the `done=false` as I need it after this.

Thanks

Comment: Surround it in a `while (!done) { /* ... */ }` loop.

Comment: Calling `Thread.start()` invokes `Thread.run()` once. Use a loop within `run() { ... }` to do things over and over or use a timer to schedule thread execution at a fixed rate.

Comment: @ZOOE - in response to your update, introduce a new boolean called isRunning, and use this boolean in your while loop, having it set to false when you want to leave the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After execution `run()` method the thread is consider as **COMPLETED** or **DEAD**  so that it run once only.

If you want to call it many time as that your updated question you can use looping.